# Where is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common

Tags: tfs, nuget

Any idea where the Nuget package for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common went? When I try to access it, I get the following message:

**The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated, has security vulnerabilities or shouldn't be used anymore.**

Answer (score 1):

The reference is always in your **VS IDE** folder rather than a nuget package of nuget.org.

You should add reference directly to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll`.